# How to change the publicPath in Create React App

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I want to change the root or public path of my app from `/` to `/something`. How? [This makes no sense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419053/react-react-scripts-publicpath) based on the title.

I'm using React Router so [this docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths) cannot be used as in to set the "homepage" in `package.json`.

I've added `webpack.config.js` to the root of the folder:

```js
module.exports = {
    publicPath: '/v2/'
}
```

Restarted and my asset, manigest etc files are still pointing at the root. This example worked with Vuejs in `vue.config.js`. How to achieve this without ejecting? I got `publicPath` from [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/config/webpack.config.js).

Comment: Use https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco/

Comment: @Kousha Thanks. Done that but having this person's issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44541165/webpack-error-bundle-js1-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your root project add a file called `.env`,
inside the file enter the path you want:

```
PUBLIC_URL=/v2/
```

this should fix your problem.

if you want to modify `webpack.config.js` in a react project created with `npx create-react-app` I suggest you to install `craco` https://www.npmjs.com/package/@craco/craco .

after the installation you need to replace some lines of your `package.json`

from

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-script start",
    "build": "react-script build",
    "test": "react-script test",
    "eject": "react-script eject"
  },
...
```

to

```
...
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
...
```

after that, in your root project add a file called `craco.config.js`

inside the file add the following code

```
module.exports = {
    configure: {
      output: {
        publicPath: '/v2/'
      }
    }
  }
}
```